# How can i read from JSON with Twig?

Tags: php, html, json, twig

I have a simple PHP file:

```
  <?php

 // Load our autoloader
 require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

 // Specify our Twig templates location
 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/views');
 // Instantiate our Twig
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);


 echo $twig->render('index.html', ['products' => $products] );
```

and now i set the "products" array for the info.

But i would take variables from a JSON file where i can insert my arrays, someone knows a way?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the file contents, json_decode() it into a variable, use it like any other variable:

```
$json = file_get_contents("test.json");
$products = json_decode($json);
```