# I want to read JSON file in my Twig template

Tags: php, json, twig

I have this php file

```
<?php

// Load our autoloader
require  __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


// Specify our Twig templates location
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/views');
// Instantiate our Twig
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);


echo json_encode ($products);

echo $twig->render('index.twig', ['$products' => $products] );
```

But i don't even know how to pass my products.json file in my index.twig, but im sure that it's reading my file because output is this one:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONLsB.png)

and my JSON file is this :

```
{
 "products":[ 
  {
    "name"         : "Notebook",
    "description"  : "Core i7",
    "value"        :  "800.00",
    "date_register": "2017-06-22"
},
{
    "name"         : "Mouse",
    "description"  : "Razer",
    "value"        :  "125.00",
    "date_register": "2017-10-25"
},
{
    "name"         : "Keyboard",
    "description"  : "Mechanical Keyboard",
    "value"        : "250.00",
    "date_register": "2017-06-23"
}
```

]
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i read from JSON with Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315773/how-can-i-read-from-json-with-twig)

Answer (score 0):

`$products` is a JSON string when encoded. Leave it decoded as you did in `$twig->render('index.twig', ['$products' => $products] );` and you can access it like a regular object.

In the twig template, you can then use :

```
{% for product in $products.products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.value }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.date_register }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```